Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server
Title:  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client Error in VS Code: Incorrect dotnet path
Body:
I'm encountering an issue when trying to run or debug a C# application in Visual Studio Code. The OmniSharp server fails to connect due to an incorrect path for the .NET SDK. The error message is as follows:
vbnet

Copy code
[Error - 12:10:05 PM] Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server. Error: Cannot find dotnet path 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe\dotnet.exe'
Environment Details

Operating System: Windows 10 (Version: 10.0.22631)

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.94.1

C# Extension Version: 2.50.25

.NET SDK Version: 8.0.402

Output of dotnet --info:
yaml

Copy code
.NET SDK: Version: 8.0.402 Commit: 70aa751718 Workload version: 8.0.400-manifests.b6724b7a MSBuild version: 17.11.4+37eb419ad Runtime Environment: OS Name: Windows OS Version: 10.0.22631 OS Platform: Windows RID: win-x64 Base Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.402\ .NET workloads installed: Configured to use loose manifests when installing new manifests. There are no installed workloads to display. Host: Version: 8.0.8 Architecture: x64 Commit: 08338fcaa5 .NET SDKs installed: 8.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] .NET runtimes installed: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App] Other architectures found: None Environment variables: Not set global.json file: Not found Learn more: https://aka.ms/dotnet/info Download .NET: https://aka.ms/dotnet/download


Steps to Reproduce

Open Visual Studio Code.

Open a C# project.

Attempt to run or debug the C# application.

Observe the error message indicating the inability to connect to the server.


Expected Behavior
The C# application should run or debug without issues, and the OmniSharp server should connect successfully.
Actual Behavior
The error message states that it cannot find the dotnet path with an incorrect file path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe\dotnet.exe.
Additional Context

The DOTNET_ROOT environment variable is not set.

The PATH variable includes C:\Program Files\dotnet\.

I have checked paths and restarted Visual Studio Code multiple times.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Verified and set environment variables.

Modified VS Code settings to specify the omnisharp.dotnetPath.

Reinstalled the C# extension.

Ensured the project configuration is correct.

Checked for conflicts with other extensions.

Restarted my computer.




Question
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue with the incorrect dotnet path? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

why is this tagged unity?

I am Working On Unity Engine, Using Vs code as My editor...While Working this Error is Popping Out

Well.. You dont mention unity, you dont mention what you have/havent installed, you only mention making a c# project, vs code is less supported by unity now, you dont mention which version, but, its less supported, you have to follow other instructions to get it to remotely work, but if you cant make a normal c# project without errors, you got other issues going on and unity is not the problem
